# JSON parse error, unable to deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` in STS 4.15.3 windows version

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data, jsonparser, jparepository

I'm new to this tool and I'm having trouble with this specific issue. I looked for an example But could not find something similar, better, I found a possible solution, but in my case It doesn't work.

I have this narrow project that resembles our famous CRUD, and I'm trying to reference the primary key from one table to another.

1. Client Entity:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "client")             
   public class Client {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Long id;

       @Column(name = "cpf", length = 14)
       private String cpf;

       @Column(name = "name", length = 100)
       private String name;

       @Column(name = "birth_date")
       private LocalDate birthDate;

       @Column(name = "address", length = 255)
       private String address;

       @Column(name = "telephone", length = 14)
       private String telephone;

       @Column(name = "email", length = 200)
       private String email;

       @Column(name = "date_register", insertable = true, updatable = false)
       private LocalDate dateRegister;

       public Client() {
           super();
       }

       public Client(Long id, String cpf, String name, LocalDate birthDate, String address, String telephone, String email, LocalDate dateRegister) {
           super();
           this.id = id;
           this.cpf = cpf;
           this.name = name;
           this.birthDate = birthDate;
           this.address = address;
           this.telephone = telephone;
           this.email = email;
           this.dateRegister = dateRegister;
       }

       public Client(String cpf, String name, LocalDate birthDate, String address, String telephone, String email, LocalDate dateRegister) {
           super();
           this.cpf = cpf;
           this.name = name;
           this.birthDate = birthDate;
           this.address = address;
           this.telephone = telephone;
           this.email = email;
           this.dateRegister = dateRegister;
       }

       @PrePersist
       public void prePersist() {
           setDateRegister(LocalDate.now());
       }

       public Long getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public void setId(Long id) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public String getCpf() {
           return cpf;
       }

       public void setCpf(String cpf) {
           this.cpf = cpf;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public LocalDate getBirthDate() {
           return birthDate;
       }

       public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) {
           this.birthDate = birthDate;
       }

       public String getAddress() {
           return address;
       }

       public void setAddress(String address) {
           this.address = address;
       }

       public String getTelephone() {
           return telephone;
       }

       public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
           this.telephone = telephone;
       }

       public String getEmail() {
           return email;
       }

       public void setEmail(String email) {
           this.email = email;
       }

       public LocalDate getDateRegister() {
           return dateRegister;
       }

       public void setDateRegister(LocalDate dateRegister) {
           this.dateRegister = dateRegister;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "Client [id=" + id + ", cpf=" + cpf + ", name=" + name + ", birthDate=" + birthDate + ", address="
           + address + ", telephone=" + telephone + ", email=" + email + ", dateRegister=" + dateRegister + "]";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Sale Entity:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "sale")
   public class Sale {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Long id;

       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
       private Client client;

       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sale")
       private List<SaleItem> items;

       @Column(name = "payment_type", length = 10)
       @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
       private PaymentType paymentType;

       @Column(name = "amount")
       private BigDecimal amount;

       public Long getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public void setId(Long id) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public Client getClient() {
           return client;
       }

       public void setClient(Client client) {
           this.client = client;
       }

       public List<SaleItem> getItems() {
           return items;
       }

       public void setItems(List<SaleItem> items) {
           this.items = items;
       }

       public PaymentType getPaymentType() {
           return paymentType;
       }

       public void setPaymentType(PaymentType paymentType) {
           this.paymentType = paymentType;
       }

       public BigDecimal getAmount() {
           return amount;
       }

       public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
           this.amount = amount;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "Sale [id=" + id + ", client=" + client + ", items=" + items + ", paymentType=" + paymentType
           + ", amount=" + amount + "]";
       }   
   }
   ```

The objective is to link the client to a sale through its primary key. These two codes refer to the sales repository and its controller:

1. SaleRepository:

   ```
   public interface SaleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sale, Long> {

   }
   ```
2. SaleController:

   ```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/sales")
    @CrossOrigin("*")
    public class SaleController {

        @Autowired
        private SaleRepository repository;

        @Autowired
        private SaleItemRepository saleItemrepository;

        @PostMapping
        @Transactional
        public void save(@RequestBody Sale sale) {
            repository.save(sale);
            sale.getItems().stream().forEach(saleItem -> saleItem.setSale(sale));
            saleItemrepository.saveAll(sale.getItems());
        }

   }
   ```

And the problem is exactly how this reference is being made. In the current `private Client client;` way , the client object is being passed in full instead of its id, that's why it throws this following error when I try to register the sale.

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "31/05/1968": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '31/05/1968' could not be parsed at index 0; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "31/05/1968": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '31/05/1968' could not be parsed at index 0<EOL> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 87] (through reference chain: MyNameIsRafaelSampaio.github.com.bruxo_vendas_ltda_api.model.Sale["client"]->MyNameIsRafaelSampaio.github.com.bruxo_vendas_ltda_api.model.Client["birthDate"])]
```

As was to be expected, since the column `birthDate`  present in the client entity is not being treated correctly in the sale entity. I did research on a possible solution but none made much sense to me, I believe for being a newbie, one of the solutions that I found more understandable was the use of the `@MapsId`  tag. I tried to make changes to adapt, but I was not successful, if you can help I will be grateful.